# How to drop SKUs based on monthly condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to drop a row based on SKU if price or quantity are not present in any given month.

My data looks something like this:

| SKU | Month | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Jan | 100 | 50 |
| 111 | Feb | 200 | NaN |
| 222 | Jan | 100 | 50 |
| 222 | Feb | 50 | 100 |
| 333 | Jan | NaN | 40 |
| 333 | Feb | 50 | 30 |
| 444 | Jan | 50 | 30 |
| 444 | Feb | 50 | 30 |

I want to keep the SKUs where price and quantity are present for all months so the subset I would be working with would be:

| SKU | Month | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 222 | Jan | 100 | 50 |
| 222 | Feb | 50 | 100 |
| 444 | Jan | 50 | 30 |
| 444 | Feb | 50 | 30 |

Comment: That sounds reasonably straightforward. What have you tried so far? Please show us your code and explain where you're having difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're reading your data, so I'm using a tab-separated string as toy example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

text = """
sku     month   price   quantity
111     Jan     100     50
111     Feb     200     NaN
222     Jan     100     50
222     Feb     50      100
333     Jan     NaN     40
333     Feb     50      30
444     Jan     50      30
444     Feb     50      30
"""
headers, *value_rows = [row.split() for row in text.strip().split('\n')]
data = [dict(zip(headers, row)) for row in value_rows]
# [{'sku': '111', 'month': 'Jan', 'price': '100', 'quantity': '50'}, {'sku': ...

all_months = set(row['month'] for row in data)

months_per_sku = defaultdict(set)
for row in data:
    # Check for each entry if it has price and quantity.
    if row['price'] != 'NaN' and row['quantity'] != 'NaN':
        # If it does, note that this SKU has this month data available.
        months_per_sku[row['sku']].add(row['month'])
# {'111': {'Jan'}, '222': {'Jan', 'Feb'}, '333': {'Feb'}, '444': {'Jan', 'Feb'}}

print('\t'.join(headers))
for row in data:
    if months_per_sku[row['sku']] == all_months:
        print('\t'.join(row.values()))
# sku     month   price   quantity
# 222     Jan     100     50
# 222     Feb     50      100
# 444     Jan     50      30
# 444     Feb     50      30
```